# Guide to latex for a mathematician

Tags: books, learning

I'm a PhD math student and I would like to learn latex quickly and effectively. Can you suggest a good book for learning latex (with an emphasis on mathematical typesetting)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: If you really want to know about math… may be [mathmode.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) helps.

Comment: [This](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) is only one of the interesting resources you can find online about Maths in LaTeX. I have a more recent version 2.41 I cannot find online at the moment...

Comment: [This](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/novices-screen.pdf) is not really too popular but I started reading it and found it very good. Maths is discussed properly in Chapter 9. Have a try...! @Manuel: perfect timing!

Comment: Good all round: [LaTeX Beginner's Guide](http://www.packtpub.com/latex-beginners-guide/book) and contains material on math.

Answer (score 0):

Most LaTeX learning resources will focus on math at some point.

After learning the basics about LaTeX, I think the [Short Math Guide](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) will give you most of what you need.